# Why doesn't Eren's Founding Titan ability to control other titans work on Rod Reiss' titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Season 3 Episode 9 of Attack on Titan, Eren tries to use his Founding Titan powers to control other titans, on Rod Reiss' titan, but he can't. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a spoiler-free answer to this.

Warning: Spoilers ahead

> You need royal blood to use the Founding Titan's ability, unfortunately Eren is not a royal descendant. When Eren first used this ability it was when he came in contact with the Smiling Titan (how she had royal blood is another spoiler).

Comment: I dont understand, what does it mean "being in contact"? Be close to another titan with royal bloodline? How about when he used the hardening skill to save his friends? isnt that another founding titan hability?

Comment: Being in contact means physically touching another person (doesn't have to a be titan as far as I know). I don't think the hardening skill is associated to the Founding Titan.

Comment: Another thing is that he need to be in contact with a Royal Blood Giant, not a royal blood human.

Comment: but at the end of the second season when all those titans went to eat that other titan after he threw a punch into the air, who was he touching? I dont remember much but wasnt he alone?

Comment: He punched the smiling titan and briefly came into contact with her, thus activating the coordinate power of the Founding Titan. If you want to know more about the smiling titan you can read the wikia, but I'm warning you, it will contain MAJOR spoilers.

Comment: @UsmanRafi That's what I thought, too, but according to wikia, Eren **must** touch a titan of royal blood to control pure titans.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it worked on the smiling Titan is because she was once dina fritz who was royal blood line which passed it down to Zeke and Eren kills her do to that fact it doesn't work on rod is because he was born of royal blood but didn't hear Eren for he rub his ears off. Therefore Eren has a founding Titan in him which makes him be able to us the means to control titian's for the royal blood line also goes through him since is dad ate Frida reiss and he ate his dad but that's all I got